# preg_match word and check if it is present in array

Tags: php

I have a string say

```
 $str =" I am engineer".
 $array_match =array('doctor','inspector','teacher');
```

What is the correct way of finding whether particular profession given in string; is present in array or not using regular expression ,I have tried below code but not getting result ,what is wrong

```
<?php 
    $str =" I am engineer"
    $array_match =aaray('doctor','inspector','teacher');
    $flag=0;
    foreach($array_match as $match)
    {

        if(preg_match('~'.$match.'~',$str)== true)
        {
             $flag=1;
        }


    else
        {
             $flag=0;   
        }
    }
    if($flag==1)
    { 
        echo "word matched .";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "word not match ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `aaray` how does it works then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not working now is that you are not breaking out of the loop when a match is found. This means if your second word matches, flag will be "1" but the loop will continue. Then if the next word is not matched, flag will be reset to "0" printing "Word not matched".

Change the line `$flag = 1` to these two:

```
$flag = 1;
break;
```

And it will work.

Comment: This is really where you caught my mistak , I want to know one thing that this will break `foreach loop` right ,even if i write this `break;` statement in `if loop's` curly brace? Why is it so ,Can you please clarify my this concept

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `else` inside your loop and add a break after finding a match. No need to reset the flag once it has been set. Also, use [**strpos()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) or [**stripos()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) instead of `preg_match`. Given your situation, there is no need to use regular expressions.

```
$str = "I am engineer";
$array_match = array('doctor','inspector','teacher');

$flag = false; // Flag defaults to false

foreach($array_match as $word) {

    // Check if profession is in string
    if (stripos($str, $word) !== false) {

        // If profession is found, set flag to true and exit loop
        $flag = true;
        break;

    }
}

if ($flag) 
    echo 'Word matched';
else
    echo 'Word not matched';
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many "correct" ways to solve the problem you have, and there is probably no "best" way (that would be a matter of opinion).

It is possible to do the search that you need **without** resorting to looping through your array of professions.  You can call [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on your array of professions to generate a single regular expression, and then you can check your string to see if there is a match to that regular expression.

For example, let's say you start with:

```
$string = " I am engineer";
$professions = array('doctor','inspector','teacher');
```

You can generate your regular expression (don't forget the the starting and ending slash) like this:

```
$regexp = '/' . implode($professions, '|') . '/';
// yields: "/doctor|inspector|teacher/"
```

This regular expression will match a string that has *doctor **or** inspector **or** teacher*.

Then you can call [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to see if there are any matches on your string.  If so, they will be be in your `$matches` array:

```
if (preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches)) {
  print "Found this profession: " . $matches[0] . "\n";
}
```

When you put it all together, you have this:

```
$string = " I am engineer";
$professions = array('doctor','inspector','teacher');

$regexp = '/' . implode($professions, '|') . '/';

if (preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches)) {
  print "Found this profession: " . $matches[0] . "\n";
}
else {
  print "No matching profession found.\n";
}
```

It's a slightly shorter piece of code, and you don't need to worry about looping through your array of professions.  Really, the bulk of the work is done in calls to `implode` and `preg_match`.

By the way, this example just looks for the first match of a profession in the test string, and it outputs that profession.  In case your test string has multiple profession matches, you would need to call `preg_match_all` and look more closely through the `$matches` array.  I'll leave that exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$string =" I am engineer";  
$array_match =array('doctor','inspector','teacher');

$result = count(array_filter($array_match, create_function('$arr','return strstr("'.$string.'", $arr);')))>0;

if($result)  
        echo "word matched";
else
        echo "not matched";
```